# how to display xml formatted jsp

Tags: xml, jsp

I have XML as a string in JSP. But this XML is in a single line. I want to display this XML string formatted in JSP.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><catalog><book id="bk101"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price>...(is going on)
```

I want to display this as follows in JSP:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>...(going on)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. I solved it by formatting the XML string in my Java Code before sending it to the JSP (you can do it in JSP also if you want):

```
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
Source source = new DOMSource(document);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Result output = new StreamResult(writer);
transformer.transform(source, output);
return writer.toString();
```

Then use c:out to display it

```
<pre>
    <c:out value="${xmlString}" /> 
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the <, > and other characters which have special meaning in HTML to their [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp). To parse use [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0306.html) method. It will parse for you.

Comment: i understood what you mean. but i dont mean how to show string in jsp. i mean how i can display this string in formatted xml with tree structure.

Comment: @omer: use method from my answer to get parsed string and display that string in jsp. it will display whole xml.

Answer (score 0):

do xsl transformation and specify option

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
```

see this [example](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_indent_an_XML_file_using_XSLT) and after this use your xml

Comment: i dont wanna display xml data in jsp. i wanna display xml file in jsp. how can i explain it. when user open the page, user will not see xml data.for example name, country. user will see all xml.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog.xml

click this link. i wanna display like this. not xml's content. just all xml.

Comment: try putting this line first `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` in your file

Answer (score 0):

Try to change "text/xml" instead of "text/html" in your jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

then put xml content without

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

So you need something like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%><catalog><book id="bk101"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price>...(is going on)
```